# Show Username and Password after Successful registration using JSP

Tags: jsp

How to show the Username and Password in the Page which I am displaying after successful Registration.

The code I developed for Registration is as follows

```
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*;" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Halcyon Technologies Pvt. Ltd.</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#D9EEFB">
    <p
      <% try
      {
       String Username;
       String Password;
       ResultSet rs;
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:OnlineExam");
       Statement st=con.createStatement();
       Statement st2=con.createStatement();
       Statement st3=con.createStatement();
       String status="s";
       st2.executeUpdate("insert into Login values('"+request.getParameter("username")+"','"
                                                     +request.getParameter("password")+"','"
                                                     +status+"')");
       st.executeUpdate("insert into Details values('"+request.getParameter("username")+"','"
                                                      +request.getParameter("name")+"','"
                                                      +request.getParameter("gender")+"','"
                                                      +request.getParameter("sel_cat")+"')");
       if(request.getParameter("sel_cat").equals("Experienced"))
       {
                  st3.executeUpdate("insert into Experienced values('"+request.getParameter("username")+"','"+request.getParameter("expyears")+"','"+request.getParameter("company")+"','"+request.getParameter("designation")+"','"+request.getParameter("salary")+"','"+request.getParameter("comAddress")+"')");
       }
        String s1 = request.getParameter("username");
        String s2 = request.getParameter("password");

        session.setAttribute("s1", s1);
        session.setAttribute("s2", s2);
        rs = st.executeQuery("select Username, Password from Login where Username='" + s1 + "'");

       if (rs.next()) 
        {
            Username=rs.getString(1);
            Password=rs.getString(2);
            System.out.println(Username);
            System.out.println(Password);
        }
       st.close();
       st2.close();
       st3.close();
       }

       catch(Exception e)
               {
           out.println(e);
               }
%>
  <font color="red" size="5"> You have registered successfully!!!<br></font>
  <font color="red" size="5"> Username :  <br></font>
  <font color="red" size="5"> Password :  <br></font>
  <p><a href="Login.jsp"><strong>Go Forward</strong></a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I could able to get the Username and Password on console, but how to display them on JSP.

The code here to display on console is

```
if (rs.next()) 
        {
            Username=rs.getString(1);
            Password=rs.getString(2);
            System.out.println(Username);
            System.out.println(Password);
        }
```

The code to display JSP is below. In this JSP i want to display Username and Password.

```
 <font color="red" size="5"> You have registered successfully!!!<br></font>
  <font color="red" size="5"> Username :  <br></font>
  <font color="red" size="5"> Password :  <br></font>
  <p><a href="Login.jsp"><strong>Go Forward</strong></a></p>
```

How to code to display Username and Password in JSP?

Comment: Small sidenote here: you want to display the password your user just entered? How is it stored? If I'm correct, you're storing it plain text, which is bad practice security-wise. Also, what is the value of `c1` before you execute the query? And can you show the query which gets sent to the DBMS?

Comment: You can't recover the password as plaintext in any properly designed authentication system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a valid SQL query:

```
"select Username and  Password from Login where Username='" + c1 +"'"
```

It should be:

```
"select Username, Password from Login where Username='" + c1 +"'"
```

However, you should use `PreparedStatement` instead of simple statements as your current SQL is very good candidate for a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack: Just think what kind of results the query would give if the variable `c1` has the value: `' or '1'='1` (this is the typical and most basic example for this kind of attack).

To correct it do something like:

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select Username, Password from Login where Username=?");
st.setString(1, c1);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Other remarks:

- **Never store passwords in plain text**, you should hash them, there are a lot of tools out there to encrypt and verify passwords.
- Try to use significative names for your variables/attributes/etc or you code will end up being impossible to read. Using a variable named `username` is way much better than `c1` and would help others understand what your code is doing.

Comment: You shouldn't encrypt them, you should *hash* them.

Comment: @EJP direct translation from Spanish, language in which *hash* isn't a verb. The -1 is way too **harsh** for an answer that actually finds and solves the problem of the OP and also gives him suggestions to improve his code.